# Is it possible to chat with more than 8 players in Battlefield 1 on the PS4?

Tags: ps4, battlefield-1, voice-chat

We have an online gaming crew who regularly play co-op together on the Playstation 4.

Playing Battlefield 1 we often field two squads/ 10 players - which is more than the limit of 8 players in PS4 Party Chat.

We'd like to keep it social and have our squads co-operate on the same side. If we run two PS4 Parties of 5 players our squads can't communicate and can get split up.

Is there any way we can have all 10 players on the same voice chat, in two squads, on the same side in Battlefield 1?

Comment: I thought the party size limit was 16 people?

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket - you can invite 16 people to a party, but only 8 can be in the party at any one time

Comment: Aha... I was not aware of this. Sony should change this feature